# Dynamic link to ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a table which is created by a jQuery component. In each row there is a select component which I can set to be linked to a ng-model, something like this:

```
<select ng-model="categories" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in categories"></select>
```

My problem is that I don;t know when it is rendered, so I had to use n ugly `$timeout`, but even calling `$scope.$apply()` it doesn't bind to the items.
How can I force binding the select with element.
P.S. I'm using AngularJS 1.6

Comment: You are using the same scope variable for both `ng-model` and `ng-options`. Change `ng-model='categories'` to `ng-model='category'`

Comment: Even doing it it shows no options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some js code (i.e. jQuery) that creates some angular html, you need to $compile all created html so bindings will work.
I.e. this:

```
angular.element(document.body).append(angular.element('<input ng-model="x"/>'));
```

will just add some html, while this:

```
angular.element(document.body).append($compile(angular.element('<input ng-model="x"/>'))($scope));
```

will add input and bind x to its value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PyIO02p3EHzpmC0cUA4V?p=preview